# Facebook Open Graph publish custom story only visible on "activity log"

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I use Facebook Open Graph to publish custom story in my android app.
I'v created the story in the Facebook application console, with the custom object and action, submitted it of review with "Explicit share" and got approved.
My problem is that I'm able to create the object, and create an action using this object, but I only see the story on my activity log (and also under "recent activities" on timeline) but no one else sees the story and it does not look as I've created it.
I use the "Explicitly Shared" fled in the action, but nothing is shown.
can someone help

Comment: Make sure your application is not still in sandbox mode. When an app is in sandbox mode, only the users involved in the development are able to see the app *and* the content it generates.

Comment: so the administrator developer and test users should see the custom story on their timeline? It's not the case for me neither..